# Let $G$ be a finite group of order $20$, and consider the representation of $G$ over $\Bbb C$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $20$, and consider the representation of $G$ over $\Bbb C$.
I know $G$ has representative of conjugacy class $e$,$g_1$,$g_2$,$g_3$,$g_4$. Number of conjugacy class of $g_1$,$g_2$,$g_3$,$g_4$ is $1,4,5,5,5$.

And character table is like the following

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& e & g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & g_4 \\ \hline
 \chi_0 & 1 &1 & 1& 1&1 \\ \hline
\chi_1 & 1 & \ 1 & \ i & -1 & -i \\\hline
\chi_2 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
\chi_4 & 1&a_2  &a_3 &a_4 &a_5  \\ \hline
\chi_5 & 4 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 \\ \hline 
\end{array}
$$

I want to figure out  what is $a_i,b_i(2≦i,j≦5)$.

Calcuraing product of characters,

$\left<\chi_1,\chi_4\right>＝0$ deduces $1＋4a_2＋5a_4＋5a_5＝0$・・・①.
In the same way,
from  $\left<\chi_2,\chi_4\right>＝0$ deduces $1＋4a_2-5ia_3-5a_4＋5ia_5＝0・・・②$.
From $\left<\chi_3,\chi_4\right>＝0$, $1＋4a_2-5a_3＋5a_4-5a_5＝0・・・③$.
From $\left<\chi_4,\chi_4\right>＝0$, $1＋4|a_2|^2＋5|a_3|^2＋5|a_4|^2＋5|a_5|^2＝20・・・④$.

I just need to solve simultaneous equation ①②③④.
But complicated and I may mistook or going wrong way.
Where I mistook the way ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The dot product is Hermitean?

Comment: It looks like the group is isomorphic to the semidirect product $C_5\rtimes C_4$ (=the holomorph of $C_5$). Why didn't you say so? You know, there are a few non-isomorphic groups of order $20$ :-)

Comment: Anyway, why is $\chi_1\chi_2$ the character of an irreducible representation? How does that help?

Comment: No. In a Hermitean dot product you use complex conjugates of coordinates of one of the vectors otherwise $<u,u>$ may not be real.

Comment: Mind you, there is a complex conjugation in the inner product so
$$\langle\chi_4,\chi_4\rangle=1+4|a_1|^2+5|a_2|^2+5|a_3|^2+5|a_4|^2.$$

Comment: ＠Jyrki Lahtonen   Yes, this group is specified from order. But this question ( and my interest ) requests to find the values of $a_i$ and $b_j$ from the given incomplete table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** the product of two linear characters is obviously again a linear character, so $\chi_4=\chi_1\chi_2$. This gives you the $a_i$'s. From this point you can use the orthogonality relations to find the $b_i$'s. Or, note that the product of a linear character with an irreducible character is again an irreducible character. So, since $\chi_5$ is the *unique* character of degree $4$, $\chi_1\chi_5=\chi_2\chi_5=\chi_5$. This immediately gives $b_3=b_4=b_5=0$. I leave it to you to calculate $b_2$.

Comment: 1.I'm beginner of representation theory, sorry to ask elementary thing, but could you tell me the definition of product of character (or references) ? 2. Is it impossible to solve just $４＋4b_2＋5b_3＋5b_4＋5b_5＝0$ and $4＋4b_2−5ib_3-5b_4＋5ib_5＝0$ and $4＋4b_2-5b_3＋5b_4-5b_5＝0$ and $16＋4｜b_2｜^2＋5｜b_3｜^2＋5｜b_4｜^2＋5｜b_5｜^2＝20$. The answer seems to be $b_2＝-1, b_2＝b_4＝b_5＝0$ and from orthogonality relation, $a_2＝1, a_4＝-1, a_5＝1, a_3＝-1$. Is it impossible to solve the simultaneously equation directly ?

Comment: If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are linear representations, they are just homomorphisms from $G$ into $\mathbb{C}^*$. Their pointwise product $\lambda \mu$ is again a homomorphism of $G$ into $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Could you tell me why  ' product of linear character is linear character' induces $χ_4＝χ_1χ_2$?

Comment: @Catsoup He just did. It completely straightforward from the definitions that this is the case (and since the product $\chi_1\chi_2$ must be one of the linear characters and it is clearly not $\chi_0$, $\chi_1$ or $\chi_2$, it must be $\chi_4$ (not sure why there is no $\chi_3$)

Comment: Could you tell me why χ1χ5 is 4 dimmensional  ?

Comment: $(\chi_1 \chi_5)(1)=\chi_1(1)\chi_5(1)=1 \cdot 4=4$.